# Lower and upper bound of the Stirling's approximation

Tags: inequality, approximation, gamma-function

Perhaps everybody has heard of the Stirling's approximation, namely:
$$ \Gamma(z)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z $$ 
Thus (the very basic example):
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}z\right) \approx\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{z}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{2e}}\right)^{z}$$
My question is: how does one obtain the lower and upper bound for the Gamma function using the Stirling's approximation? I've heard that $$ \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{z}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{2e}}\right)^{\color{red}{z-1}}<\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}z\right)<\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{z}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{2e}}\right)^{\color{red}{z+1}} $$ is a very "ugly" and unproper way (moreover it doesn't always work). So what's the best way to obtain the lower and upper bound?

Comment: The upper and lower bounds from Robbins 1955 are useful for the factorial, i.e. integer values of the gamma function, but the proof does not automatically extend to all (positive) reals. It took me a long time to find this, but Gordon 1994, _A Stochastic Approach to the Gamma Function_, in Theorem 5 extends the bounds to all real numbers. (The factorial version is mentioned in the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates )

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), you will find this very nice inequality $$\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac 12}e^{-n} \leq n! \leq en^{n+\frac 12}e^{-n}$$ which would give you good approximations of upper and lower bounds for the $\Gamma$ function.

For example $$\Gamma(12.3456)\approx 9.33280\times 10^7$$ while the above formulae give $\approx 9.26452\times 10^7$ and  $\approx 1.00468\times 10^8$

$$\Gamma(123.456)\approx 8.85315\times 10^{203}$$ while the above formulae give $\approx 8.84713\times 10^{203}$ and  $\approx 9.59416\times 10^{203}$

Comment: And what about the situation from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402034/approximation-of-the-gamma-function? how does he obtain the bound by computing the "extra-term"?

Answer (score 1):

The paper [here](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0308210513001558) establishes the following simple bounds for the gamma function:

$$
\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{z}} \left( {\frac{z}{{\rm e}}} \right)^z  < \Gamma (z) < \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{z}} \left( {\frac{z}{{\rm e}}} \right)^z \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }}} \right),
$$

valid for $z>0$. Additional bounds are provided in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1967180):

$$
\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{z}} \left( {\frac{z}{{\rm e}}} \right)^z {\rm e}^{\frac{1}{{12(z + h)}}}  < \Gamma (z) < \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{z}} \left( {\frac{z}{{\rm e}}} \right)^z {\rm e}^{\frac{1}{{12z}}} 
$$

for $z>0$, with

$$
h = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\max_{t > 0} \frac{{\log (1 +t^2 )}}{t} = 0.12807872 \ldots \,.
$$

(It appears that the optimal value for $h$ is $0.06257405 \ldots\;$.)